# a.s convergence of $X_n=X^n$, where $X\sim U(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

**Study the a.s convergence of $X_n=X^n$, where $X\sim U(0,1)$**

**My attemp:**

My definition of a.s convergence is : A sequence of r.v $X_n$converges a.s to $X$ $\iff$ $\mathbb{P}(X_n\not\to X)=0$.

$\mathbb{P}(X_n\not\to X)=\mathbb{P}(X^n\not\to X)=0$

If $X \in [0,1), X^n\to 0$

If $X =1, X^n\to 1$

If $X \in [1,+\infty), X^n\to \infty$

If $X \in [-\infty,0),  X^n\to +\infty,$ if $n$ is even and to $-\infty $if $n$ is odd$

**I am on the right track here?**
**should I say that  $(X^n\not\to X) = \mathbb{R}\setminus (0,1)$ ? or is it just $(X^n\not\to X) = \{1\}$  because a uniform variable takes values only on $[0,1]$ and I should not be analyzing the values outside of it? I am also not sure if there is convergence to 1 for X=1, an to 0 for X in [0,1)**

Comment: strange definition... your sequence converges to $0$ a.s. because $X\in [0,1)$ a.s. and thus $X^n\to 0$ a.s.

Comment: @Surb do you think the definition is wrong? I t says that the set where $X_n$ does not converge has measure 0, that is that it converges up to a zero measure set, or that it converges a.s. what is so strange about it? Is it uncommon?

Comment: it's not wrong, but it looks strange... it seems more natural to write as $\mathbb P\left\{\lim_{n\to \infty }X_n=X\right\}=1$ instead of $\mathbb P\left\{\lim_{n\to \infty }X_n\neq X\right\}=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You are making it too complicated. $1=P(0<X<1)\leq P(X^{n} \to 0)$ because $t^{n}\to 0$ whenever $0<t<1$. This finishes the proof.

Comment: I am not sure where that inequality comes from

Comment: And something else don't we have convergence to 1 when X=1?

Comment: That does not matter because $P(X=1)=0$. @mathlover